# Loop through multiple columns in R

Tags: r, loops

I have the following code I'd like to run for multiple columns in a data frame called ccc.

```
ccc %>% 
  group_by(LA) %>%
  summarise(Def = sum(DefaultOct05 == 'Def'),
            NDef = sum(DefaultOct05 != 'Def'),
            DRate = mean(DefaultOct05 == 'Def'))
```

LA is the name of one of the columns.  How would I set up a loop to run through a number of different columns?

I've tried the following.

```
for (i in 26:ncol(ccc)) {
    ccc %>% 
        group_by(i) %>%
        summarise(Def = sum(DefaultOct05 == 'Def'),
                  NDef = sum(DefaultOct05 != 'Def'),
                  DRate = mean(DefaultOct05 == 'Def'))
}
```

But I get the following error message.

Error in resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)) : 
  unknown variable to group by : i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What most people will miss in your question is a reproducible data set. Without it, its often very hard to reproduce your problem and solve it.

If I got you right, your data-set looks like the one above:

```
set.seed(1)
ccc=data.frame(Default=sample(c(0,1),100,replace = TRUE),LA=sample(c("X","Y","Z"),100,replace = TRUE),DC=sample(c("A","B","C"),100,replace = TRUE))
```

do.call() - applies rbind() to the subsequent elements.
lapply(dat,function(x)) applies the function to every element of dat - in our case columns.

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(rbind,lapply(ccc, function(Var) {  
  dat=data.frame(Var,Default=ccc$Default) %>% group_by(Var) %>% summarise(Def=sum(Default),NDef=n()-sum(Default),DRate=mean(Default))
  return(as.data.frame(dat))


}
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm getting the following error message.   

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors.

I've converted the values in these columns to factor.  Would I just put the factor() function in front of the Var. For example, fiction(factor(Var)).

Also, I'm only trying to loop through columns 26:35, wouldn't I need to start with a for loop?

Comment: @Eitan:  1 .Do you get this error running the code above? 2. I think your "DefaultOct05" variable is a factor and not a numeric  - right? - Use as-numeric("DefaultFactor") 3. If my answer solved your question - please mark the answer as "solved".

Comment: Thanks @Jogi.  It was for the code above, and when I used as.numeric it works.

Answer (score 0):

> "LA is the name of one of the columns"

Actually, group by dplyr construction works on variables inside the columns. I guess you want to do other things.

If you want to apply the same function to different columns you could use summarize_at.

```
df <- data.frame( id = c(1:20),
              a1 = runif(20),
              b1 = runif(20),
              c1 = runif(20) 
              )

library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise_at(c("a1","b1","c1"), funs(med = median,
                                             avr = mean))

# result: 
# a1_med    b1_med    c1_med    a1_avr    b1_avr    c1_avr
# 1 0.6444056 0.5266252 0.6420554 0.5605837 0.4983654 0.5546381
```